# Maven Sonarqube Jacoco 0 coverage

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project and I am seeing 0% coverage when I go into Sonarqube, but seeing proper coverage when I view the Jacoco reports in `{module}/target/site/index.html`

Here is the relevant part of my pom.xml

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Here is my `sonar-project.properties` file

```
## Sonar Scanner Settings File
# SonarQube info
sonar.host.url=xxx

# Project config
sonar.language=java
sonar.projectKey=project
sonar.projectName=project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
sonar.github.repository=lendup/project
sonar.sources=module1/src/main/java,module2/src/main/java
sonar.tests=module1/src/test/java,module2/src/test/java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Test Reports
sonar.junit.reportPaths=module1/target/surefire-reports,module2/target/surefire-reports
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=module1/target/jacoco.exec,module2/target/jacoco.exec

## Java
sonar.java.binaries=module1/target/classes,module2/target/classes
sonar.java.source=1.8
```

My project does not use the maven surefire plugin, instead it is installed manually to the local repo like

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=assets/surefire-junit4-2.17.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.surefire -DartifactId=surefire-junit4 -Dversion=2.17 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DcreateChecksum=true
```

Comment: "My project does not use the maven surefire plugin" -> How do you get code coverage without running your unit tests?

Comment: Please include the full command line (i.e. options, goals) that you use to invoke maven.